# Subclass method code being ignored when calling super method within

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I am creating a program with text-based input.
Every time input is received, there is both text-based (System printing) output and graphics representation output using a JFrame.

I have the class `Player` which extends `UiPlayer`.

Methods in `UiPlayer` control the player around the UI 2D map. Methods in `Player` change variables to display for the text-based output.
Relevant code in `Player`:

```
public class Player extends UiPlayer
{
  private MyDirection facing;

  public Player(.....)   //irrelevant arguments
  {
    super(.....);
    facing = MyDirection.EAST;
  }


  /**
  *  make the player turn right, both in text and in GUI window
  */
  public void turnRight()
  {
    super.turnRight();
    if(facing == MyDirection.NORTH)
    {facing = MyDirection.EAST;} 
    else if(facing == MyDirection.WEST)
    {facing = MyDirection.NORTH;}
    else if(facing == MyDirection.SOUTH)
    {facing = MyDirection.WEST;}
    else
    {facing = MyDirection.SOUTH;}
  }

  /**
  * make the player turn 180 degrees, both in text and on graphics window
  */
  public void turnAround()
  {
    super.turnAround();
    if(facing == MyDirection.NORTH)
    {facing = MyDirection.SOUTH;}
    else if(facing == MyDirection.WEST)
    {facing = MyDirection.EAST;}
    else if(facing == MyDirection.SOUTH)
    {facing = MyDirection.NORTH;}
    else
    {facing = MyDirection.WEST;}
}
```

However, for some reason, although `turnRight()` and `turnLeft()` work perfectly, when `turnAround()` is called, if it includes calling the super method within, the super method is called, player turns in the GUI and all other code to change the text-based direction (i.e. `facing`) seems to be ignored.

If I don't include the super method, the value of `facing` changes every time, perfectly.

I have tried renaming the methods, and placing `super.turnAround()` after the if statement.

Edit: Also, I don't have access to UiPlayer's code, I just have the method documentation. It states  | void  |  turnAround()  |  Turn the player around so it faces the opposite direction.

Any ideas? ><

Comment: Can you add the super- Method please.

Comment: I would guess that super.turnAround() does the same thing as Player.turnAround(), with the result that the player turns around twice and ends up facing in the same direction.

Comment: Wheer is UiPlayer class where you defined `turnAround` method?

Comment: I don't have access to the super method's code, just the documentation that it turns the Player in the opposite direction. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If I were you,* and you can not get `turnAround` to work and *you don't have access to fix the code and the class and see what is going on exactly,*

I would then call **twice** `turnLeft` or `turnRight` which is basically `turnAround` if you think about it..

It's not a super optimised way to deal with it or whatever, *but it should solve your problem :)*